# Populating a JList using a JButton and Populating the JTextField using DoubleClick on the Jlist

Tags: java, swing, jlist, mouselistener

I am trying to populate a JList through a button, and then populate the JTextField using DoubleClick on the previously populated Jlist.

Code:

```
 private void extractUsedVariablesActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                     
     // TODO add your handling code here:


     if(arguments.size() > 0)
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please complete the predicates before accessing this");

     DefaultListModel lista1 = new DefaultListModel();
     for (int i = 0;i<variableList.size();i++)
        {
        if (!lista1.contains(variableList.get(i)))
        {
        lista1.addElement(variableList.get(i));
        }
        }
     argVariables_List.setModel(lista1);  
     revalidate();
     repaint();

    if (lista1.size()>0){
         System.out.println("got here1");
         MouseListener mouseListener2 = new MouseAdapter() 
              {          
                public void mouseClicked1(MouseEvent mouseEvent2) 
                 {
                  JList varList = (JList) mouseEvent2.getSource();
                      if (mouseEvent2.getClickCount() == 2) 
                         {
                         System.out.println("may be");
                         int index varList.locationToIndex(mouseEvent2.getPoint());
                        if (index >= 0) 
                         {
                          Object o2 = varList.getModel().getElementAt(index);
                          System.out.println(o2.toString());         
                        }                          
                      }
                    }                     
                  };
                   argVariables_List.addMouseListener(mouseListener2);
    }

}
```

It is working fine till populating the Jlist. But when I try the doubleclick operation and print the text at the clicked index I am not getting any output neither any errors. Please suggest me if I am missing something.

Comment: God please, indent your code before sharing with others...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public void mouseClicked1(MouseEvent mouseEvent2)
```

There is no such method in the MouseListener interface. (note the "1").

Make sure you include `@Override` in the line above the method and you will get a compiler error when you make a typo.

```
@Override
public void mouseClicked1(MouseEvent mouseEvent2)
```